# C - unsigned int going negative (-ve)

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

What I know is - `UNSIGNED INT` cannot take negative values.
If I take the `maximum value` of an `UNSIGNED INT` and increment it, I should get `ZERO` i.e. the `minimum value` and if I take the `minimum value` and decrement it, I should get the `maximum value`. 
Then, why is this happening ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int ui;
    ui = UINT_MAX;
    ui ++;
    printf("ui = %d", ui);

    ui = 0;
    ui --;
    printf("\n");
    printf("ui = %d", ui);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
ui = 0
ui = -1
```

Comment: its because of int overflow

Comment: `%d` ? shouldn't that be `%u` ?

Comment: I have to read the specification to be sure, but IIRC either the overflow or the underflow is most likely [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `%d` says to treat it as an int, and it did.

Comment: C11 6.2.5/9: _"A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the value to an ellipsis function (`printf`). You should expect nothing about the signedness here.

The `%d` in the format string controls the sign of the displayed value. There is a cast inside the `printf` function since you selected the `%d`. That's why you see a `signed` value that is equivalent to the binary value FFFFFFFF<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Assuming a 32 bit width for integer.

Answer (score 3):

From 'man 3 printf':

> d, i   The  int  argument is converted to signed decimal notation

So, although the type of `ui` is `unsigned int`, `printf` is interpreting it as a `signed int` and showing it as such.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you using `%d` format specifier that says `printf` to treat your number as a signed integer.
Try using `%u` to output unsigned value and you get the desired result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int ui;
    ui = UINT_MAX;
    ui ++;
    printf("ui = %u", ui);
    ui = 0;
    ui --;
    printf("\n");
    printf("ui = %u", ui);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output:

```
ui = 0
ui = 4294967295
```

Check out the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) on possible format specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%u")`  should be used for `unsigned int`s.